# How to get text in the selected List in ListBox in WPF?

Tags: wpf, c#-4.0, wpf-controls

I have 2 ListBox ( "Types" and "Products")
 "Types" gets all its data from database. I want to list in "Products" which is type selected in "Types" listbox.

I want to do it in the WPF.
Can you help me?
Thank you for your attention

Comment: does one type has one or many products? how does the data from your database look like? post some code please.

Answer (score 2):

i assume that types is somewhat related to products. then you can do the following.
(you have to set the right DataContext of course :)

```
 public class Types
 {
      public List<Product> MyProducts {get; set;}
 }
```

xaml.cs or mvvm

```
 {
     public List<Types> MyTypesCollection {get; set;}
 }
```

xaml

```
 <ListBox x:Name=lstTypes ItemSource="{Binding MyTypesCollection}" />
 <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding ElementName=lstTypes, Path=SelectedItem.MyProducts}"/>
```

Comment: I have to tables for each listbox. Types and medicines. Please help me.